# jQuery .wrap() not wrapping around a cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

```js
(function($) {
  $.extend({
    notify: function(options, duration) {
      var defaults = {
        inline: true,
        href: '',
        html: ''
      };
      var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

      var body = $('body'),
        container = $('<ul></ul>').attr('id', 'notification_area'),
        wrapper = '<li class="notification"></li>',
        clone;

      if (!body.hasClass('notifications_active')) {
        body.append(container).addClass('notifications_active');
      }

      if (options.inline == true && options.href) {
        clone = $(options.href).clone().wrap(wrapper);
      }

      clone.css('visibility', 'hidden').appendTo(container);

      var clone_height = 0 - parseInt(clone.outerHeight());
      clone.css('marginBottom', clone_height);

      clone.animate({
        marginBottom: 0
      }, 'fast', function() {
        clone.hide().css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn('fast');
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $.notify({
      inline: true,
      href: '#alert'
    }, 3000)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sambenson/RmkEN/

In the above example I'm cloning an element and attempting to wrap it with and `<li></li>` but the clone isn't being wrapped at all. Why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The key is this line in the [.wrap() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

> This method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

.wrap() only operates on an element already in the DOM. So, you will need to insert it, then wrap it.

Comment: No, you don't have to. jQuery can operate on any DOM Element, doesn't matter if they are or aren't in the DOM. The key part (and misleading part) is that .wrap returns the inner element, not the parent that wrapped the child. If you want to get it, you have to write .parent as in the following console tested code:

$('<div class="child"/>').wrap($('<div class="parent"/>')).parent()

Comment: As @DénesPapp pointed out, the element does not need to be in the DOM. Since this is the accepted answer it would be great if the wrong information were removed.

Answer (score 23):

The confusing part is that `.wrap()` returns the inner element, not the parent element.

So you have to use the **parent** object of the wrapped one as follows:

```
var $divA= $("<div/>").addClass('classA'),
    $divB= $("<div/>").addClass('classB');

console.log( $divA.wrap($divB).parent() );
```

(`$divA.parent()` is equal to `$divB` after the wrapping)

So the key part is that `$divA.wrap($divB)` returns `$divA`, NOT `$divB`

see the reference:

> This method returns the original set of elements for chaining
> purposes.

Please note:
The elements DON'T have to be in the DOM, jQuery can operate on them without them already having been inserted into the DOM.